# How to split the columns in python script by specifying characters?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to extend this working code by adding extra columns..The sample file given below.. Now the issue is that, I need to take all the items within box braces [] as one column like total columns as 6. How to write an condition to proceed with it?

Sample.txt

```
7.020000    993.000000  755.000000  FAIL    3   [ 62 02 01 23 26 30 35 C0 C0 C0 C0 ]
7.020000    993.000000  803.000000  FAIL    5   [ 62 02 01 23 26 30 35 C0 C0 C0 C0 ]
7.020000    993.000000  811.000000  FAIL    2   [ 62 02 01 23 26 30 35 C0 C0 C0 C0 ]
7.020000    993.000000  828.000000  PASS    1   []
7.020000    993.000000  876.000000  PASS    6   []
7.020000    993.000000  894.000000  FAIL    3   [ 62 02 01 23 26 30 35 C0 C0 C0 C0 ]
7.020000    993.000000  913.000000  FAIL    5   [ 62 02 01 23 26 30 35 C0 C0 C0 C0 ]
7.020000    993.000000  954.000000  FAIL    2   [ 62 02 01 23 26 30 35 C0 C0 C0 C0 ]
```

Any suggestions would be helpful!!!!!!!!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
fig.savefig('Test2.png')#, dpi=600)

ax = Axes3D(fig) # ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_title("Plot 3d",fontsize=14)
ax.set_xlabel('Voltage (V)', fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel('Pulse Delay(ms)', fontsize=12)
ax.set_zlabel('Pulse Width(ms)', fontsize=12)
ax.grid(True, linestyle='-', color='0.75')

data = np.genfromtxt('./Sample.txt', dtype=[('col1', 'f8'), ('col2', 'i16'), ('col3',   'i16'), ('col4', 'S15'), ('col5',  'i16'), ('col6',  'S24')])


m = data["col4"]
data1 = data[m == "PASS"]
data2 = data[m != "PASS"]

for dat, color in [(data1, 'g'), (data2, 'r')]:

    # Don't forget that having empty data columns may raise exceptions ...
    try:
        x, y, z = dat['col1'], dat['col2'], dat['col3']
        ax.scatter(xs=x, ys=y, zs=z, s=50, c=color, marker='o', linewidths=0)
    except:
        pass

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a job for regex:

```
data = np.fromregex('./Sample.txt',
    r'(\d+\.\d+)\s+(\d+)\.\d+\s+(\d+)\.\d+\s+(FAIL|PASS)\s+(\d+)\s+\[\s*(.*?)\s*\]',
    dtype=[('col1', 'f8'), ('col2', 'i16'), ('col3', 'i16'),
           ('col4', 'S15'), ('col5', 'i16'), ('col6',  'S24')])
```

Comment: Thnx rczajka... The code works fine.. only thing is, I face some lagging in the performance when I run a large txt file...

Answer (score 0):

Suggest using `delimiter` to specify column widths, which seem to be consistent for you:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('./temp.dat', dtype=[('col1', 'f8'), ('col2', 'i16'), 
     ('col3',   'i16'), ('col4', 'S15'), ('col5',  'i16'), ('col6','S37')], 
     delimiter = (10,13,13,4,7,40))
```

Produces for row 0:

```
(7.02, 993, 755, 'FAIL', 3, ' [ 62 02 01 23 26 30 35 C0 C0 C0 C0 ]')
```

You may need to strip the string columns further, and then process the array-like values as you need.

If you cannot rely on the column widths, you may be forced to go with text searching for '[' and ']' line-by-line.

Comment: Thx for the reply.. Actually the code is not working fine as expected for a txt file with 40,000 lines to be parsed...